# How to connect .emacs to Emacs, installation through brew

Tags: syntax, emacs, homebrew

Installation like this:

1. `curl -fsSL https://rawgit.com/kube/42homebrew/master/install.sh | zsh`
2. `brew install emacs`

After that, the file `.emacs` from the root folder of the user stopped connecting. Therefore, the syntax is disabled.
How to connect it to the Homebrew-installed Emacs ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. This question might get more attention on emacs.stackexchange.com so I would recommend you post it there instead of here. But please try to write more clearly, and get someone else to check your English if possible.

Comment: In Emacs, what does `C-h v user-init-file` show you?